# Why doesn't SIGKILL terminate a stopped program (yes)?

Tags: shell, job-control

I'm using *Ubuntu 14.04* and I'm experiencing this behavior I can't seem to understand:

1. Run the `yes` command (in the default shell: *Bash*)
2. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to stop `yes`
3. Run `jobs`. Output:
   `[1]+  Stopped     yes`
4. Run `kill -9 %1` to stop `yes`. Output:
   `[1]+  Stopped     yes`
5. Run `jobs`. Output:
   `[1]+  Stopped     yes`

This is on Ubuntu `3.16.0-30-generic` running in a parallels virtual machine.

Why didn't my `kill -9` command terminate the *yes* command? I thought *SIGKILL* can't be caught or ignored? And how can I terminate the *yes* command?

Comment: That's interesting. SIGKILL should work and it does on my Linux Mint 17. For any other signal, you'd normally need to send it SIGCONT afterwards to make sure the signal gets received by the stopped target.

Comment: Does bash really print "Stopped" for a process that is _suspended_?

Comment: Kernel version (`uname -a`) please

Comment: `Linux ubuntu 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. I'm running Ubuntu in Parallels Desktop.

Comment: @black most shells say "Stopped". tcsh says "Suspended" and zsh says "suspended". A cosmetic difference. Of somewhat more importance is the fact that bash prints an identical message for STOP and TSTP, where all other shells mark the annotate the STOP message with `(signal)` so you can tell the difference.

Comment: Use `set -b` for asynchronous job-control notifications.

Answer (score 10):

Signals are blocked for suspended processes.  In a terminal:

```
$ yes
...
y
y
^Zy

[1]+  Stopped                 yes
```

In a second terminal:

```
$ killall yes
```

In the first terminal:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 yes

$ fg
yes
Terminated
```

However `SIGKILL` can't be blocked.  Doing the same thing with `killall -9 yes` from the second terminal immediately gives this in the `yes` terminal:

```
[1]+  Killed                  yes
```

Consequently if `kill -9 %1` doesn't terminate the process right away then either `bash` isn't actually sending the signal until you `fg` the process, or you have uncovered a bug in kernel.

Comment: Some background details: When issuing Ctrl+Z in your terminal bash sends a `SIGTSTP` (which is the blockable version of `SIGSTOP`) to the active process. This puts the process in a frozen state where the kernel won't schedule it. That also inhibits signal processing (except for the `SIGCONT` signal which unfreezes the process) and therefore prevents the process from being killed right away.

Comment: @mreithub Yes, that's exactly what happens.  Well, `SIGSTOP` is actually sent in very different conditions.

Comment: SIGKILL, unlike other signals, is not blocked for suspended processes. Sending the KILL signal to a suspended process kills it — asynchronously, but in practice basically immediately.

Comment: @Gilles That's what I was trying to illustrate above: `SIGTERM` is blocked, but `SIGKILL` isn't.  Anyway, according to a comment from OP, the problem seems to be that `jobs` doesn't detect that the process has died, not the process not being killed by `kill -9 %1`.

Comment: But I can reproduce s1m0n's behavior on my system (Debian, amd64, bash 4.3.30).

Comment: While `SIGKILL` cannot be blocked, there is no guarantee that it will be delivered within any meaningful time.  If a process is suspended pending blocking I/O, for example, `SIGKILL` will not arrive until the process wakes.  This could potentially be never, if no I/O occurs.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', "suspended process kills it — asynchronously". In that case, what is exit status of a `kill` command? 0 or 1?

Comment: @AlexMartian `kill` returns 0 if it could deliver the signal, which basically means that the PID is valid and the calling process has the appropriate permission. What happens next (signal ignored, signal handler runs, signal kills the process, signal reaction delayed because the target process is in a non-interruptible system call, …) doesn't delay `kill` returning and doesn't affect its return status even if it hasn't returned yet.

Answer (score 8):

## Don't panic.

There's nothing funky going on.  There's no kernel bug here.  This is perfectly normal behaviour from the Bourne Again shell and a multitasking operating system.

The thing to remember is that *a process kills itself*, even in response to `SIGKILL`.  What's happening here is that the Bourne Again shell is getting around to things *before* the process that it just told to kill itself gets around to killing itself.

Consider what happens from the point where `yes` has been stopped with `SIGTSTP` and you've just executed the `kill` command with the Bourne Again shell:

1. The shell sends `SIGKILL` to the `yes` process.
2. *In parallel*:

   1. The `yes` process is scheduled to run and immediately kills itself.
   2. The Bourne Again shell continues, issuing another prompt.

The reason that you are seeing one thing and other people are seeing another is a simple race between two ready to run processes, the winner of which is entirely down to things that vary both from machine to machine and over time.  System load makes a difference, as does the fact that your CPU is virtual.

In the interesting case, the detail of step #2 is this:

1. The Bourne Again shell continues.
2. As part of the internals of the built-in `kill` command it marks the entry in its job table as *needing a notification message printed* at the next available point.
3. It finishes the `kill` command, and just before printing the prompt again checks to see whether it should print notification messages about any jobs.
4. The `yes` process hasn't had the chance to kill itself yet, so as far as the shell is concerned the job is still in the stopped state.  So the shell prints a "Stopped" job status line for that job, and resets its notification pending flag.
5. The `yes` process gets scheduled and kills itself.
6. The kernel informs the shell, which is busy running its command line editor, that the process has killed itself.  The shell notes the change in status and flags the job as notification pending again.
7. Simply pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> to cycle through the prompt printing again gives the shell the chance to print the new job status.

The important points are:

- Processes kill themselves.  `SIGKILL` isn't magical.  Processes check for pending signals when returning to application mode from kernel mode, which happens at the ends of page faults, (non-nested) interrupts, and system calls.  The only special thing is that the kernel doesn't allow the action in response to `SIGKILL` to be anything other than immediate and unconditional suicide, with no return to application mode.  Importantly, processes need to both be making kernel-to-application-mode transitions *and* be scheduled to run in order to respond to signals.
- A virtual CPU is just a thread on a host operating system.  There's no guarantee that the host has scheduled the virtual CPU to run.  Host operating systems are not magical, either.
- Notification messages aren't printed when the job state changes happen (unless you use `set -o notify`).  They are printed when next the shell reaches a point in its execution cycle that it checks to see whether any notifications are pending.
- The notification pending flag is being set twice, once by `kill` and once by the `SIGCHLD` signal handler.  This means that one can see *two* messages if the shell is running ahead of the `yes` process being rescheduled to kill itself; one a "Stopped" message and one a "Killed" message.
- Obviously, the `/bin/kill` program doesn't have any access to the shell's internal jobs table; so you won't see such behaviour with `/bin/kill`.  The notification pending flag is only set the once, by the `SIGCHLD` handler.
- For the same reason, you won't see this behaviour if you `kill` the `yes` process from another shell.

Comment: That's an interesting theory, but the OP gets to type `jobs` and the shell still sees the process as alive.  That would be one unusually long scheduling race condition. :)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your elaborative answer! I certainly makes sense and clears up quite a few things.. But as stated above, I can run multiply `jobs` commands after the `kill` which all still indicate the process is just stopped.
You however inspired me to keep experimenting and I discovered this: the message `[1]+  Terminated yes` is printed as soon as I run another external command (not a shell builtin like `echo` or `jobs`). So I can run `jobs` as much as I like and it keeps printing `[1]+  Stopped  yes`. But as soon as I run `ls` for example, Bash prints `[1]+  Terminated  yes`

Comment: lcd047 didn't read your comment to the question; which was important and should have been edited into the start of the question, properly.  It's easy to overload a host operating system such that guests appear to schedule very strangely, from within.  Just like this, and more besides.  (I once managed to cause quite odd scheduling with a runaway Bing Desktop consuming most of the host CPU time.)

Comment: No, that's not quite it. `kill -9 %1` sends the KILL signal immediately. The job may or may not be killed before the next prompt (there's a race condition here), but it'll definitely be killed before a human can type or even paste `jobs`, so it should show as killed by that time.

Comment: @Gilles The problem seems to be that `jobs` doesn't notice that the process has actually died...  Not sure what to make about the status being updated by running another command though.

Comment: Even Gilles didn't see the comment. This is why you should put this sort of important stuff _in the question_, not bury it in a comment. Gilles, the answer clearly talks about delays in _delivering_ a signal, not delays in _sending_ it. You've mixed them up. Also, read the questioner's comment (and indeed the bullet point that it is given here) and see the very important wrong fundamental assumption that you are making. Virtual processors do not necessarily run in lockstep, and are not magically capable of always running at full speed.

Comment: Maybe a note or two on `set -b` would be worthwhile here? Oh, my mistake, `set -o notify` *is* mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

What you're observing is a bug in this version of bash.

`kill -9 %1` does kill the job immediately. You can observe that with `ps`. You can trace the bash process to see when the `kill` system call is called, and trace the subprocess to see when it receives and processes the signals. More interstingly, you can go and see what's happening to the process.

```
bash-4.3$ sleep 9999
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 9999
bash-4.3$ kill -9 %1

[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 9999
bash-4.3$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 9999
bash-4.3$ jobs -l
[1]+  3083 Stopped                 sleep 9999
bash-4.3$
```

In another terminal:

```
% ps 3083
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3083 pts/4    Z      0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
```

The subprocess is a [zombie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). It's dead: all that's left of it is an entry in the process table (but no memory, code, open files, etc.). The entry is left around until its parent takes notice and retrieves its exit status by calling the [`wait` system call or one of its siblings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_(system_call)).

An interactive shell is supposed to check for dead children and reap them before printing a prompt (unless configured otherwise). This version of bash fails to do it in some circumstances:

```
bash-4.3$ jobs -l
[1]+  3083 Stopped                 sleep 9999
bash-4.3$ true
bash-4.3$ /bin/true
[1]+  Killed                  sleep 9999
```

You might expect bash to report “Killed” as soon as it's printing the prompt after the `kill` command, but that isn't guaranteed, because there's a race condition. Signals are delivered asynchronously: the `kill` system call returns as soon as the kernel has figured out which process(es) to deliver the signal to, without waiting for it to be actually delivered. It's possible, and it does happen in practice, that bash has time to check on the status of its subprocess, find that it's still not dead (`wait4` doesn't report any child death), and print that the process is still stopped. What is wrong is that before the next prompt, the signal has been delivered (`ps` reports that the process is dead), yet bash still hasn't called `wait4` (we can see that not only because it still reports the job as “Stopped”, but because the zombie is still present in the process table). In fact, bash only reaps the zombie the next time it needs to call `wait4`, when it's run some other external command.

The bug is intermittent and I couldn't reproduce it while bash is traced (presumably because it's a race condition where bash needs to react fast). If the signal is delivered before bash checks, everything happens as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Something funky may be happening on your system, on mine your recipe works nicely both with and without the `-9`:

```
> yes
...
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 yes
> jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 yes
> kill %1
[1]+  Killed                  yes
> jobs
>
```

Get the pid with `jobs -p` and try to kill it as `root`.

Comment: May I ask what distribution/kernel/bash version you're using? Maybe your bash's internal `kill` command goes the extra mile and checks if the job is frozen (you might want to try finding out the PID of the job and kill it using `env kill <pid>`. That way you'll be using the actual `kill` command and not the bash builtin.

Comment: bash-4.2-75.3.1.x86_64 on opensuse 13.2. The kill cmd is not the internal one: `which kill
/usr/bin/kill`

Comment: `which` is not a bash-builtin, so `which <anything>` will always give you the path to the actual command. But try comparing `kill --help` vs. `/usr/bin/kill --help`.

Comment: Ah, right. Indeed, it's the builtin `kill`.