# Schrodinger's cat

Tags: cat, background-process, c++

When I run a cat command as a background process,

```
$ cat &
```

and then try to kill it,

```
$ killall -v cat
```

it says that it killed cat with signal 15, but also that cat was only stopped. Upon running `$ ps`, I see that it is still running. It isn't until I call `$ fg` that it is finally terminated.

It appears to be related to waiting for input, because when simulating cat in c++,

```
string line;
while(getline(cin, line))
   cout << line << endl;
```

the same thing happens, but for a simple `while(true);` loop, the process is killed successfully.

It also appears to be necessary that it is a background process because when I run `$ cat` and in another terminal `$ killall -v cat` it also works fine.

What is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate, [Why can't I kill a SIGSTOP'd process with a SIGTERM, and where is the pending signal stored?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/298644/100397)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run

```
cat &
```

you should see a message saying

```
[1]+  Stopped                 cat
```

shortly thereafter (perhaps with a different job number). This is because `cat` tries to read from its standard input, so when it’s run in the background, it ends up being stopped.

[Stopped processes don’t receive signals other than `SIGKILL` until they are resumed (continued)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209288/86440). This is what is happening here: your `SIGTERM` is only delivered when the process is continued, which happens when you return it to the foreground.