# linux: kill -9 process success only on second attempt

Tags: kill, chroot, job-control

I'm currently solving [umount /chrootedpath /dev/pts after several chroot(s): target is busy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/759434/umount-chrootedpath-dev-pts-after-several-chroots-target-is-busy).

I've found part of the problem - two processes still running `ps` had shown as `sudo choot` command. They were in `Ss` / `T` status. Strangely `kill -9` exited with `1`, I was puzzled cause I know `uninterruptable sleep` fails to be killed, not others. So I've tried to run with `strace` to find out more. But this time it exited with 0. For both processes first failed, one with `strace` succeeded.

A bit later I used `lsof` to find several more processes, for them both `kill -9` and with `strace` failed. But soon after they disappeared.

Web search found posts about sending SIGINT, also [Why doesn't SIGKILL terminate a stopped program (yes)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209288/why-doesnt-sigkill-terminate-a-stopped-program-yes) where there is comment

> SIGKILL, unlike other signals, is not blocked for suspended processes.
> Sending the KILL signal to a suspended process kills it —
> asynchronously, but in practice basically immediately. – Gilles 'SO-
> stop being evil' Jun 12, 2015 at 22:30

Maybe "asynchronously", but second `kill -9` succeeded, AFAIK it fails if the process no longer there. And if "asynchronously", what is expected exit status of the first command? Can somebody please explain what happened and why?